# ¿Cómo asignar valor por defecto a un atributo en POO en JAVA?

Tags: java

Hola comunidad Stackoverflow,

Soy nuevo en el tema y estoy realizando un pequeño ejercicio de POO en Java el cual algunas abreviaturas no me quedan claras:

Instrucciones

Crear una clase Cuenta

Atributos de cuenta:

id (cadena de caracteres)
Tipo (Cadena de caracteres)
Saldo(decimal)

Para cada atributo se debe aplicar el principio de encapsulamiento
Los atributos tipo y saldo deben tener metodos get y set
El atributo id solo tendra el metodo get, de manera que no podra ser modificado desde otra clase
**El valor por defecto del atributo sera A** ESTA PARTE SIGO SIN ENTENDER COMO LA ASIGNO

Constructores de Cuenta:

**Crear un constructor que reciba el id de cuenta y setee el atributo id del objeto con
este valor, además debe setear el atributo tipo en el valor por defecto (A), no es
necesario setear el valor de saldo porque el atributo tiene el valor 0.0 por defecto.**

En este ejemplo no aplica el constructor vacío, ya que al no poseer un método setId,
una vez creado el objeto con el constructor vacío, no tendría forma de darle valor al
Id de cuenta y una cuenta sin Id no tiene sentido. (NO crear el constructor vacío)
Crear un constructor que reciba los tres atributos de cuenta y setee sus valores.

Clase Cuenta

public class Cuenta {

```
private String id;
private String tipo;
private float saldo;





//Metodos

public void imprimir(){
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("CUENTA ");
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("Numero de cuenta: " + id);
    System.out.println("Tipo: " + tipo);
    System.out.println("Slado: " + saldo);
}


public void imprimirConMiEstilo(){
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("CUENTA ");
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("Numero de cuenta: " + id);
    System.out.println("Tipo: " + tipo);
    System.out.println("Saldo: " + saldo);
}


//Constructores



public Cuenta(String id) {
            
    this.id = id;
}
public Cuenta(String id, String tipo, float saldo) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}
//Getters y Setters
public String getTipo() {
    
    return tipo;
}
public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
public float getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}
public void setSaldo(float saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

Clase TestCuenta

public class TestCuenta {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("03476");
    cuenta1.setSaldo(675);
    
    Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("03476","C",98);
    
    Cuenta cuenta3 = new Cuenta("03476");
    cuenta3.setTipo("C");
    
    
    System.out.println("-----Valores inciales-----");
    cuenta1.imprimir();
    cuenta2.imprimir();
    cuenta3.imprimir();
    System.out.println("-----Valores modificados---");
    
}
```

}

Al ejecutar me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun el ejercicio el valor por defecto del  tipo debe ser A pero marca como null, como se agrega esto al constructor? si alguien me explica como dejar ese valor, aparte si lo demás esta bien, gracias.

Comment: Algo mas rapido podria ser que al momento de declarar tu variable "tipo", le asignes un valor por defecto, es decir :  private String tipo = "A"; .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESPUESTA RAPIDA**

Crear un segundo constructor con parámetros por defecto

```
public Cuenta(String id, float saldo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tipo = "A";
    this.saldo = saldo;
}
```

Donde asignamos al parametro **tipo** el valor **"A"**

---

Si creamos un objeto y no le pasamos el parámetro tipo, por defecto será "A"

Cuenta cuenta5 = new Cuenta("03476",8000.00);

---

cuenta5.imprimir();

Numero de cuenta: 03476

Tipo: A

Slado: 8000.00

Answer (score -2):

Para setear un atributo por defecto solo debes darle ese valor en el constructor.

```
public Cuenta(String id, float saldo) {
  this.id = id;
  this.tipo = "A"; // de esta manera le das un valor por defecto a tipo
  this.saldo = saldo;
}
```